# On Cloud9 ide, how do you un/reinstall mysql DB from the workspace?

Tags: mysql, sails.js, cloud9-ide

I followed the setup for mysql in the cloud9 docs. `show databases;` looked normal for mysql.

I ran my nodejs app (following a [tutorial on sails.js](https://github.com/grokible/sails-tutorial-1/blob/master/TUTORIALS/TUTORIAL01.md) framework) which was supposed to connect to the configured db, then set up the model... in this case, a User table with fname and lname.

When starting the node app, it immediately gave a permissions error. When i did `show databases;` again, now the only table is `information_schema`.

9_9 < eyeroll

Fine. Whatever. I figure at this early stage of the tutorials, I'd just blow away the DB and start over. `mysql-ctl install` gave me the warning about wiping existing data, and then it proceeded to do nothing.

So how do I blow away the DB and start over? I'd rather not do a new workspace.

[edit] If there's a better place to ask this question, where would that be?